# entity framework lazy loading loads only one item in collections

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I built two applications using entity framework and I'm trying to use lazy loading to fetch related entities. On one of them lazy loading related entities works as expected, but I get a problem with the other one. I'm still able to load related entities, but once the collection is retrieved, I get only one single entity in it, even there should be more.

I used:

```
base.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

in my datacontext. Also, I made my related collections virtual:

```
public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

I spent more than one day now to look for the difference between the two applications and I can't find any. One application has locations that contains events and that works fine. the other one has categories that contains products and that's the one not working. has anyone encountered a similar problem?! what am I overlooking.

The problem is that when I'm iterating over my products in a view, I get to see only one element in the collection:

```
@foreach(var Product in Model.Products) { @Product.Name }
```

But then I get only one product name, even there should be more than one!

Comment: Did you test if eager loading returns more than one element (by using `Include("Products")` when you load the category)?

Comment: yes I did, it's excatly the same. so actually it's probably not really a matter of lazy loading. I just keep getting only one entity back in a collection.

Comment: Hm, did you double check if you really have more than one product for the category in question? You could do a simple test by writing a SQL query in SQL Server Management Studio (or some similar tool if you are using another DB): Say, your problem is with category 5. Then check `select * from products where categoryId = 5` (`categoryId` is the foreign key in products table) and check how many rows are returned.

Comment: man; that *is* lazy loading. (sorry; couldn't resist the rimshot moment)

Comment: yes I did double check. but even when I'm using eager loading with include I get only one product. the weird thing is that I don't get a null reference for products, but I only get one item back in that collection!

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue? I'm using EF 5 and I'm getting the exact same problem...

Comment: Okay, after a massive amount of time wasted on this I just deleted a ton of old code and the problem fixed itself ... I wonder what the cause was... very curious.

Answer (score 0):

Recently came across a similar issue. Our problem was that the table had a multiple column key, but one of the columns was nullable so it couldn't be used as an Entity Key.

From EF's point of view the entities we were trying to load all had the same key, so only the first one was loaded.

We had to make a unique ID column for this table to solve the issue.